# Diffrents usage of ! operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

can someone explain to me the diffrence between `default` and `default!`

for example:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; } = default!;
```

to:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; } = default;
```

Comment: `!` is *null forgiving operator*, so you assign `default` value (which is `null` in case of `string`) and do not want to get warning for this: note that `FirstName` is of type `string`, not `string?`.

Comment: From an IL-perspective both statements are identical. The null-forgiving operator is just an indicator for the compiler to **not** throw a warning if you attempt to assign `null` to a non-nullable reference-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `!` is a [null forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving). In your case you assign `default` value
(which is `null` in case of `string`) to `string` property and don't want to get *warning*:

```
 // FirstName should not be null
 // but you assign default (null) value to it
 // and don't want to get warning about it (you know what you are doing)
 public string FirstName { get; set; } = default!;
```

Another possibility is to allow `null` (note `string?` instead of `string`):

```
 // FirstName can be null
 // We assign default (null) value to it
 public string? FirstName { get; set; } = default;
```

In case of

```
 // FirstName is not suppose to be null
 // But we assign default (which is null)
 // Compiler can warn you about it
 public string FirstName { get; set; } = default;
```